# jQuery Ajax - response is not expected

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have created an API service with drupal and rest ui.

If I copy and paste URL in chrome I get this response

This is raw my ouput

```
[{"teste":"Instala\u00e7\u00e3o do Microsoft Intune nos Dispositivos M\u00f3veis"},{"teste":"App 3 Minutos"},{"teste":"SD-Wan"}]
```

And parsed output

```
[
 {
   "teste": "Instalação do Microsoft Intune nos Dispositivos Móveis"
 },
 {
  "teste": "App 3 Minutos"
 },
 {
  "teste": "SD-Wan"
 }
]
```

So far so good.

Then I create an ajax request to the same link and request hit on "error" function but the response is this:

```
{"readyState":4,"responseText":"[{\"teste\":\"Instala\\u00e7\\u00e3o do Microsoft Intune nos Dispositivos M\\u00f3veis\"},{\"teste\":\"App 3 Minutos\"},{\"teste\":\"SD-Wan\"}]","status":200,"statusText":"OK"}
```

Almost the samething as expected.

On the chrome console I get http code 200 and the preview match with my API output

[print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2Zzy.png)

[print2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Q5rh.png)

My jQuery ajax code

```
$.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url:"http://teste.dd:8083/timeline",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(data) {
            var kk = JSON.stringify(data);
            $('.teste').text(JSON.parse(kk));
            alert('entrou');
        },
        error: function (data) {
            var kk = JSON.stringify(data);
            $('.teste').text(kk);
            alert('nao');
        }
    });
```

The request always hit on the error function but no throw any error on console and http code is always 200.

I am doing something wrong with ajax request?

With CURL request everything works great, but I need to do this request with ajax, because I don't want to load the page in every request (will have different requests).

If someone has another approach is welcome :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is not JSONP response....

Comment: JSONP is actually a script request and totally different than ajax request for JSON. Just the remove the `P` in the `dataType`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, now my response is what I expected :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using JSONP dataType, then you need to compose the response a little differently. The `callback` parameter is automatically added to the request, and it will need to be used when responding. For example, if the request is of the form

```
GET /some-url?callback=jQuery8761232
```

and result must be

```
[{"teste":"Instala\u00e7\u00e3o do Microsoft Intune nos Dispositivos M\u00f3veis"},{"teste":"App 3 Minutos"},{"teste":"SD-Wan"}]
```

then response body must be

```
jQuery8761232([{"teste":"Instala\u00e7\u00e3o do Microsoft Intune nos Dispositivos M\u00f3veis"},{"teste":"App 3 Minutos"},{"teste":"SD-Wan"}])
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for explain me a little more about it, it help a lot, not I am getting the expected response :)